Custom Hotspot Configuration on Android 14 with Root Permissions
I’m working on an academic project where I need to modify the default behavior of the hotspot functionality on an Android device. My goal is to start a hotspot programmatically and configure it to redirect HTTP and HTTPS traffic through a local proxy server. Unfortunately, despite having root permissions on my device running Android 14, the hotspot does not start as expected.
Here’s an overview of what I’m trying to achieve:
Disable Wi-Fi
Set up hostapd and dnsmasq for hotspot functionality
Configure IP forwarding and IP tables
Redirect HTTP and HTTPS traffic to a local proxy server
I have created an Android app that uses Kotlin to execute shell commands for these configurations. However, the hotspot fails to start, and I’m receiving an error related to the hostapd process not being found.
Here’s the relevant code:
private lateinit var proxyServer: ProxyServer
private val PROXY_HTTP_PORT = 8080
private val PROXY_HTTPS_PORT = 8443

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

enum class HotspotState {
    IDLE,
    STARTING,
    STARTED,
    STOPPING,
    STOPPED,
    ERROR
}

private var hotspotState = HotspotState.IDLE

companion object {
    const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1001
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    proxyServer = ProxyServer()
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

private fun executeShellCommand(command: String): String {
    return try {
        val process = ProcessBuilder("su", "-c", command)
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start()
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
        val output = reader.readText()
        val exitCode = process.waitFor()
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            throw IOException("Command \"$command\" failed with exit code $exitCode. Output: $output")
        }
        output
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw IOException("Error executing shell command", e)
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
        throw IOException("Command execution interrupted", e)
    }
}


fun startHotspot(ssid: String) {
    if (hotspotState != HotspotState.IDLE && hotspotState != HotspotState.STOPPED) {
        return
    }

    hotspotState = HotspotState.STARTING

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            // Commands to start the hotspot without a password
            val commands = listOf(
                "svc wifi disable",
                "mkdir -p /data/misc/hostapd",
                "mkdir -p /data/misc/dnsmasq",
                "echo 'interface=wlan0\n" +
                        "driver=nl80211\n" +
                        "ssid=$ssid\n" +
                        "hw_mode=g\n" +
                        "channel=6\n" +
                        "auth_algs=1\n" + // Open authentication
                        "wpa=0' > /data/misc/hostapd/hostapd.conf",
                "echo 'interface=wlan0\ndhcp-range=192.168.43.2,192.168.43.20,12h\ndhcp-option=3,192.168.43.1\ndhcp-option=6,192.168.43.1' > /data/misc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf",
                "chmod 755 /data/misc/hostapd/hostapd.conf",
                "chmod 755 /data/misc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf",
                "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward",
                "iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -s 192.168.43.0/24 -j ACCEPT",
                "iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -d 192.168.43.0/24 -j ACCEPT",
                "iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.43.0/24 ! -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE",
                "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_HTTP_PORT",
                "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_HTTPS_PORT",
                "service call connectivity 24 i32 0 i32 0 i32 0 s16 random",
                "hostapd /data/misc/hostapd/hostapd.conf > /data/misc/hostapd/hostapd.log 2>&1 &",
                "dnsmasq -C /data/misc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf > /data/misc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.log 2>&1 &"
            )

            for (command in commands) {
                val output = executeShellCommand(command)
                Log.d("HotspotDebug", "Command: $command\nOutput: $output")
            }

            // Check if `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` are running
            val hostapdRunning = executeShellCommand("pgrep hostapd")
            val dnsmasqRunning = executeShellCommand("pgrep dnsmasq")
            Log.d("HotspotDebug", "Hostapd Running: $hostapdRunning")
            Log.d("HotspotDebug", "Dnsmasq Running: $dnsmasqRunning")

            // Start the proxy server
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                proxyServer.startHttpProxy(PROXY_HTTP_PORT)
                proxyServer.startHttpsProxy(PROXY_HTTPS_PORT)
            }

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                hotspotState = HotspotState.STARTED
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Hotspot started and proxy server running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                hotspotState = HotspotState.ERROR
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error starting the hotspot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun stopHotspot() {
    if (hotspotState != HotspotState.STARTED) {
        return
    }

    hotspotState = HotspotState.STOPPING

    // Commands to stop the hotspot
    val commands = listOf(
        "killall hostapd",
        "killall dnsmasq",
        "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward",
        "iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_HTTP_PORT",
        "iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_HTTPS_PORT",
        "iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 192.168.43.0/24 ! -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE",
        "iptables -D FORWARD -i wlan0 -s 192.168.43.0/24 -j ACCEPT",
        "iptables -D FORWARD -i wlan0 -d 192.168.43.0/24 -j ACCEPT"
    )

    try {
        for (command in commands) {
            executeShellCommand(command)
        }

        // Stop the proxy server
        proxyServer.stopHttpProxy()
        proxyServer.stopHttpsProxy()

        hotspotState = HotspotState.STOPPED
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hotspot stopped and proxy server halted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        hotspotState = HotspotState.ERROR
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error executing root commands", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

Issues Encountered:
The `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` services are not starting. The command pgrep hostapd returns no results, indicating that hostapd may not be running.
The hotspot is not being activated as expected.
Device Specifications:
Android version: 14
Device: Moto G04
Root permissions: Granted
What I’ve Tried:
Verified that all shell commands are executed with root permissions.
Checked that paths and permissions for configuration files are correctly set.
Ensured the existence of hostapd and dnsmasq binaries.
Questions:
Are there any known issues or additional steps required to successfully start hostapd and dnsmasq on Android 14?
Is there a more reliable way to check if hostapd and dnsmasq are running?
Are there any specific log files or debugging methods that might help identify why these services are failing?
Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
